# Real-time Sentiment Analysis of Twitter Hashtags with Spark || Error Starting Streaming Service

Tags: twitter, apache-spark, streaming, ibm-cloud

I just recently started working with IBM Bluemix and wanted to give the spark streaming section a shot.

I have started working with 2 tutorials, which serve as an introduction to Sentiment Analysis of Twitter Hashtags with Spark and Watson.

- [Real-time Sentiment Analysis of Twitter Hashtags with Spark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZbP3b20P00)
- DW005 Analyzing Sentiment in Twitter Hashtags ( to be found in_https://developer.ibm.com/dwcourses/courses/)

However, in none of the provided cases I was able to start the spark Stream.

Both of the tutorials use provided [Github project's](https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/spark.samples/tree/master/streaming-twitter/notebook) iPython notebooks to show the example application using Spark Streaming.

This is an example exception log of the exceptions which I encountered using the first notebook.

```
Registering JaasConfiguration: /tmp/pMftPERZFap2a9SH/jaas.conf
Setting hadoop configuration for swift container
https://kafka-rest-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:443/admin/topics
https://kafka-rest-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:443/admin/topics
https://kafka-rest-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:443/admin/topics
default location of ssl Trust store is: /usr/local/src/spark160master/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/lib/security/cacerts
Twitter stream started
Tweets are collected real-time and analyzed
To stop the streaming and start interacting with the data use: StreamingTwitter.stopTwitterStreaming
Receiver Started: KafkaReceiver-0
Receiver Stopped: KafkaReceiver-0
Reason: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value com.ibm.cds.spark.samples.StatusDeserializer for configuration value.deserializer: Class com.ibm.cds.spark.samples.StatusDeserializer could not be found.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsumerConfig.java:194)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:380)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:363)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:350)
    at com.ibm.cds.spark.samples.dstream.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$38.apply(SparkContext.scala:1997)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$38.apply(SparkContext.scala:1997)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
 : Error starting receiver 0
```

You will see  some sections in the notebook where you need to enter credentials (Twitter App,Kafka Service Credentials). At first I thought it is a credential related, so I rechecked several times if it was a credential issue.Then I tried taking a look at the different classes used in the sample project and the ones mentioned in the error log, but I can't seem to resolve the issue.

I guess the answer to the issue lies within these 3 lines of code:

```
Reason: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value com.ibm.cds.spark.samples.StatusDeserializer for configuration value.deserializer: Class com.ibm.cds.spark.samples.StatusDeserializer could not be found.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:48)
```

Please provide some guidance on how I can fix this. I'd love to move on and try various new things, but I need to make sure what kind of problem this is.

Comment: Hi,

Please import all the classes so that you would not hit this issue of class not found. Import this right after the %Addjar of the assembly jar.
import com.ibm.cds.spark.samples._

But i think this seems like an intermittent issue.

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: Hi charles,  thank you for your guidance. I tried what you proposed but I guess it is an issue with the sample project Code. I just contacted the author of the project via github, I hope he will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

There was a change in the Spark Service that caused this issue. A fix has been provided. Can you please try to run the app again.
Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am also following the Real-Time Sentiment Analysis Tutorial. Apparently the fix is working, as I am able to start the Spark stream and the output of the notebook shows that it collects records.

However the dashboard does not create any charts and shows 0 processed tweets. There are no errors in the logs of the app. I would appreciate any advice.

UPDATE: Managed to run the dashboard app by changing the configs for the Watson Tone Analyzer in the notebook since it's not a beta anymore.

```
config.setConfig("watson.tone.url","https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api")
```